# Where can host some server side logic without having a web site?

Tags: hosting

I'd like to host some php or perl/cgi script, without having a full blown web site, does anybody know someone is offering this kind of service, free, hopefully.
Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can sign up for a developer account with Amazon Web Services and get a server instance of your choice for free for one year - http://aws.amazon.com/

Comment: I've looked into this, AWS product line is a little confusing, do you know if I can run cron jobs using AWS too?

Comment: its a fully features linux box, you can run whatever you choose. you SSH onto the box as if it where a physical server.

Answer (score 1):

You could run your own Linux or Windows webserver - both are completely capable of hosting as simple or complex a site you want. Unless you want to make this script available for others to use as a service, there's no need to find an "outside" provider.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, [Free File Hosting](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=free+file+hosting&cp=7&qe=ZnJlZSBmaWhvc3Rpbmc&qesig=uKQibXgyiaE-ZXCSV-Glzw&pkc=AFgZ2tnSAWlQCeHdFuMLc-5GoXNMEecOdJ9HA7ipngk0s4VXK715rAWvFl4ibAbQuJXwKaCdyIBHmd-iyeTWlxFAxBo0wUZxVA&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=0c&aqi=&aql=&oq=free+fihosting&pbx=1&bav=on.1,or.&fp=18e4c0cc530c3619).  Or, if you don't need to actually access the files from anywhere, and you just want them hosted somewhere, [gist](https://gist.github.com/) might work well for you.